# Gap in-between image grid

Tags: html, css, grid, positioning

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
} 

.photos {
  padding: 5%;
  background-color: #27ae60;
  box-sizing: content-box;
 }

 .photos > .photos-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 .photos > .photos-wrapper > .photo-1 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
 }

.photos > .photos-wrapper > .photo-1 > img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0%;
 }

 .photos > .photos-wrapper > a > button {
  border: none;
  background-color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  margin: 2% 2%;
  cursor: auto;
  padding: 2% 6%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="photos">
 <div class="photos-wrapper wrapper">
  <div class="photo-1">
   <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/2c/57/83/2c57831c6f450a30dc21bd4353b3107a.jpg" alt="Mountain Photography"> 
  </div>

  <div class="photo-1">
   <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/376212686_1280.jpg"> 
  </div>
  <div class="photo-1">
   <img src="http://www.airpixa.co.uk/images/architectural-photography-london-skyline.jpg?crc=4158542412" alt="Mountain Photography"> 
  </div>

  <div class="photo-1">
   <img src="http://www.larissajoice.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/M-Shed-Wedding-Photography-Bristol_0212.jpg" alt="Mountain Photography"> 
  </div>

  <div class="photo-1">
   <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XdYEzui3Ttc/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Mountain Photography"> 
  </div>

  <div class="photo-1">
   <img src="https://nhd.usgs.gov/photos/08_Hells_Canyon.jpg" alt="Mountain Photography"> 
  </div>

 </div> 
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWQJgO

As seen here, I'm trying to make an image grid, but there is a gap between the row of images which I'd like to get rid of. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this style: `.photos img { display: block; }`

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/peNagz)

Comment: Sweet! All works, mind telling me what that does specifically? Thanks. :)

Comment: It sets the image as a block, you can see the effect if you play it on this site https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: @aaronfty `img`'s by default are `display: inline-block` which is what is creating that white space (see [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) as to why and other possible solutions)... it states for inline-block elements _"The reason you get the spaces is because, well, you have spaces between the elements - in the HTML markup - (a line break and a few tabs counts as a space, just to be clear)"_

Comment: @aaronfty, if this answer has helped you to solve your problem, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it and also give it an up-vote :)

Comment: @zgood technically an `img` is "replaced content" which behaves similar to an inline element. https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/